# Understanding Bankers Rounding in .NET

Tags: c#, bankers-rounding

As I understand, the *default* rounding mode in .NET is "Bankers Rounding", which follows these rules:

- If the digit to round by is less than 5, then round down.
- If the digit to round by is equal to 5 then round to the nearest even number.
- if the digit to round by is greater than 5 then round up.

We can demonstrate this with the following example:

```cs
double[] values = {1.14, 1.15, 1.16, 1.24, 1.25, 1.26};
foreach (double value in values)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(value, 1));
}

// 1.1 (1.14: round down)
// 1.2 (1.15: round to even)
// 1.2 (1.16: round up)
// 1.2 (1.24: round down)
// 1.2 (1.25: round to even)
// 1.3 (1.26: round up)
```

Then I tried this:

```cs
double value = 1.23456;
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(value, 3));

// 1.235
```

My expectation was that this would result in `1.234` by the following logic:

- `1.234` is *even*
- The number to round by is `5`, therefore it should round towards even.

So, why does this produce `1.235`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your misunderstanding is where you say "*If the digit to round by is...*" when it's really all the digits, all the quantity after that which is being rounded.

In `1.23456` you are rounding `.00056` which is greater than `0.0005` so it rounds up.

Banker's rounding only applies at exactly the halfway, to break the tie. Round `1.23350` or `1.23450` to three places and they will both go to `1.234`.